# Combining gulp-sourcemaps with gulp-csso and gulp-sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

I'm trying to get this part of my `gulpfile.js` to work:

```
gulp.task('compileSass', function() {
    return gulp.src(folders.src+'/scss/*scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(folders.dest+'/css'));
});

gulp.task('minifyStyles', ['compileSass'], function() {
    return gulp.src(folders.dest+'/css/style.css')
    .pipe(maps.init())
    .pipe(minCss({
        sourceMap: true
    }))
    .pipe(maps.write('./'))
    .pipe(rename('style.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(folders.dest+'/css'));
});
```

I'd like dev tools to show the `.scss` files. I'm not sure if it has to do with the `rename()` or if I'm calling my sourcemaps at the wrong time, but when I check the dev tools, the source is always `style.min.css`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an initial mapping on your sass task. You need to call this twice, and set `loadMaps` appropriately per the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps#init-options). Try the following...

```
gulp.task('compileSass', function() {
  return gulp.src(folders.src+'/scss/*scss')
  .pipe(maps.init()) /* `init` here */
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(folders.dest+'/css'));
});

gulp.task('minifyStyles', ['compileSass'], function() {
  return gulp.src(folders.dest+'/css/style.css')
  .pipe(maps.init({
    loadMaps: true /* `init` again, load prior from sass */
  }))
  .pipe(minCss({
    sourceMap: true
  }))
  .pipe(maps.write('./'))
  .pipe(rename('style.min.css'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(folders.dest+'/css'));
});
```